# Can git diff be configured to not indicate a conflict on created files with same content?

Tags: git, git-diff, merge-conflict-resolution

Scenario: a new file has been created in a remote branch. A file with the same file name and contents has been created in the local branch.

Is it possible to configure **git diff** so that it doesn't indicate this file is a merge conflict?

I'm using git v1.9.4.

Comment: `mergetool` does not detect conflicts - it only displays things and allows you to select the bits you want to do specific things with. `git diff` and various other internal utilities are what actually calculates the differences, including the conflicts.

Comment: Ah. Good point. I'll update.